# Retrieve GMB reviews with associated media

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I am trying to retrieve the reviews of a GMB location with its associated media.

the endpoint for retrieving reviews
(`GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{name=accounts/*/locations/*/reviews/*`)
returns a list of reviews with the following fields :

```
{
  "name": string,
  "reviewId": string,
  "reviewer": {
    object (Reviewer)
  },
  "starRating": enum (StarRating),
  "comment": string,
  "createTime": string,
  "updateTime": string,
  "reviewReply": {
    object (ReviewReply)
  }
}
```

but without any media information.

Do have you have any idea for this ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While review media may be visible on Google Maps, it is currently not possible to retrieve that data via the [GMB API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews#Review).